# edraw how to open file HttpOpenFileFromStream using php

Tags: php, file

edraw open file using HttpOpenFileFromStream in php

I am using this javascript code on load event

```
document.OA1.HttpInit();
document.OA1.HttpAddpostString("DocumentID", "sample5.docx");
document.OA1.HttpOpenFileFromStream("http://localhost/rte/action_open_file.php", "Word.Application");

php code action_open_file.php

  header("http/1.1 200 OK");
  $doc_file_name = $_REQUEST["DocumentID"];
  $file_size = filesize($doc_file_name);
  $file = fopen($doc_file_name,"r");
  $data = fread($handle,$file_size);
  fwrite($handle,$data);
  fclose($handle);
```

But it opens empty file in web page but the sample5.docx has some text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS code is fine. Just replace your `action_open_file.php` code with the following:

```
<?php     
    $filename = $_REQUEST["DocumentID"];

    echo "Get Stream Successfully!";

    echo "EDA_STREAMBOUNDARY";

    $fp=fopen("$filename","r");

    print fread($fp,filesize("$filename"));

    fclose($fp);

    echo "EDA_STREAMBOUNDARY";
    exit();
?>
```